# Inconsistent behavior of wmctrl in maximizing terminal from .bashrc

Tags: bash, terminal, wmctrl

I've got this

```
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b add,maximized_vert,maximized_horz
```

inside my .bashrc in order to maximize my terminal upon opening. The odd thing is that it seems to work only randomly, sometimes resulting in a fullscreened terminal and sometimes not, with no discernable pattern. Entering the above command into an already-open terminal is always successful.

I should note that the command `xdotool windowsize $(xdotool getactivewindow) 100% 100%` (from [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/384746) answer), which achieves a similar effect, also causes the same sporadic behavior when placed in my .bashrc. Again, it always works when run from an already-open prompt. Further, *sometimes* when this command does not work, I'll recieve the following error message before the first prompt:

```
XGetWindowProperty[_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW] failed (code=1)
xdo_get_active_window reported an error
There are no windows in the stack
Invalid window '%1'
Invalid argument count, got 3, expected 2
Usage: windowsize [--sync] [--usehints] [window=%1] width height
If no window is given, %1 is used. See WINDOW STACK in xdotool(1)
--usehints  - Use window sizing hints (like font size in terminals)
--sync      - only exit once the window has resized
```

This makes me think that the whole error balances on finding the currently active window.

I'm using Mint 19.3 with XFCE4, and my terminal is urxvt. What could be causing this inconsistent behavior?

Comment: You are almost certainly correct in it having difficulty in either finding the active window or it may not yet be mapped. Perhaps putting a `sleep 1` or if your implementation supports it `sleep 0.3` before the wmcrl. However the bigger question is why do you do this, rather than just opening the terminal at the maximum size rather than opening it at a default size and then resizing it straight away.

Comment: You're absolutely correct. `sleep 0.1` seems to more than sufficient. An option `urxvt -geometry` also exists, which seems to solve the problem without a delay with the appropriate values. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378). There is a race between the terminal being displayed and the shell startup script trying to find and resize it. The OP found that a `sleep 0.1` was sufficient to allow the window to be found as the active one.

However the correct thing to do is to open the terminal with the correct initial size rather than open it at some default size and then resize it. The initial size can be specified either via defaults loaded into the X server, typically with the `xdb` program or else using the standard `-geometry` command to the terminal emulator.